# Profinite groups as Galois groups over $\Bbb C(X)$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, riemann-surfaces, profinite-groups

$\newcommand{\Q}{\Bbb Q}
\newcommand{\N}{\Bbb N}
\newcommand{\R}{\Bbb R}
\newcommand{\Z}{\Bbb Z}
\newcommand{\C}{\Bbb C}
\newcommand{\A}{\Bbb A}
\newcommand{\ab}{\mathrm{ab}}
\newcommand{\Gal}{\mathrm{Gal}}
\newcommand{\prolim}{\varprojlim}
$
It is known that every finite group is isomorphic to the Galois group of some finite extension $K / \C(T)$, using Riemann existence theorem (Remark 2.14 a) in Völklein, *Groups as Galois groups, an introduction*).

> Is every profinite group $G$ of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ isomorphic (as topological group) to the Galois group of some extension of $\C(X)$ ?

If not, what if we require these profinite groups to be abelian, or/and torsion-free?

**Ideas** :

Notice that not all profinite groups are Galois groups over $\C(X)$, since $\Gal(L/K) \subset L^L$ has cardinality $2^{|L|}$ (when $L$ is infinite), which is at most $2^{| \overline{\C(X)}|} = 2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$. By a work of Haran and Jarden (2000), one knows that the absolute Galois group of $\C(X)$ is the profinite completion of the (discrete) free group $F_{2^{\aleph_0}}$, which has cardinality $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ (I think). So I could also ask about profinite groups of such cardinality, but I'm sticking to ${2^{\aleph_0}}$ for now.

Every group of cardinality ${2^{\aleph_0}}$ is a quotient of $F_{2^{\aleph_0}}$, but I'm not sure if every profinite group of such cardinality is a topological quotient of $\widehat{F_{2^{\aleph_0}}}$ (i.e. quotient by a closed subgroup).

(An analoguous question for $\Q$ was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2849501)).

Comment: I think [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2982960/functional-equation-of-the-hasse-weil-function-of-an-elliptic-curve?noredirect=1#comment6156824_2982960) about finding simpler / more general examples than $\frac{L(s+1/2,|\chi|)L(s-1/2,|\chi|)}{L(s+1/2,\chi)L(s-1/2,\chi)}$ of $f_n(s) = f_n(-s), F(s) = \sum_n f_n(s)$ meromorphic, $ F(s)\ne F(-s)$ would be interesting

Comment: @reuns : yes, please ask it, I would be also interested! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. It is a theorem of Douady (see e.g. Theorem 3.4.8 in Szamuely's "Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups") that the absolute Galois group of $\mathbb C(X)$ is isomorphic to the free profinite group on the set $\mathbb C$. This can be deduced in purely group-theoretic way from the results you already know thanks to Riemann existence theorem, namely that for any finite set $S\subseteq\mathbb C$, the quotient parametrizing covers unramified outside $S\cup\{\infty\}$ is isomorphic to free profinite group on $S$. Analogous results hold for any algebraically closed field of characteristic zero.

Now, any profinite group with at most $2^{\aleph_0}$ elements is a quotient of a free profinite group on $2^{\aleph_0}$ generators, meaning it appears as a Galois group of an extension of $\mathbb C(X)$.

We can in fact give a precise characterization of groups which appear this way: these are those profinite groups which have a dense subset of size $2^{\aleph_0}$. I would expect not every profinite group of cardinality $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ to have such a subset, but I don't have a counterexample off the top of my head.

Comment: Thanks, I essentially knew everything. The main point is to know why any profinite group with at most $2^{\aleph_0}$ elements is a quotient BY A CLOSED SUBGROUP of a free profinite group on $2^{\aleph_0}$ generators. May you expand on that?

Comment: @Watson That there is a continuous map from the free profinite group to the given group is just the universal property of free profinite groups. The kernel is then closed because it is preimage of a closed singleton.